# erlang monitor and demonitor

Tags: erlang, monitor

My question is simple.

If one process call `monitor` and doesn't call `demonitor` and dead. Is it any side-affect to the system? Is there any trouble later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when a process dies all of it's resources will be freed.